# Process.waitFor() not waiting

Tags: java, linux, process

I am developing a `Java` application wherein I am compiling and runnimg `C` code. I am opening a new `RedHat Linux` terminal using the following code and running the `a.out` file.

```
public void run() throws Exception
{
 String[] arg={"gnome-terminal","-e","./a.out"};
 Process P=Runtime.getRuntime().exec(arg);
 P.waitFor();
}
```

The problem I am facing is that `P.waitFor();` does not work and the terminal shows the output and exits immediately, and I cannot see the output. If I put `getchar();` at the end of `C` code only then I can see the complete output. I need to know a way through which I will not have to put `getchar();` at the end and still see the output.

Comment: There are settings in gnome-terminal for what should happen when the command finishes. Not sure if you can control this setting from the command line.

Comment: Why are you trying to launch `./a.out` in a "gnome-terminal"; what's wrong with running `./a.out` directly?

Comment: I tried `hold the terminal open` in settings. But the last `printf()` of the c program is not being displayed. How do i fix it.